# Get SharePoint List data & Bind to Gridview by Client Script

Tags: client-object-model, gridview

I need to get data from SharePoint List using Client Script (JavaScript) and bind same data to GridView using Client Script (JavaScript, JQuery, etc...)

kindly suggest me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/sharepoint/1009/sharepoint-webpart-angularjs-knockoutjs) for you and it is the combo of REST and AngularJS.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically enough of what you are trying to do to give you more detail than this, but I would look into using Knockout to data-bind objects.

[Something similar to this task board.](http://johnliu.net/blog/2012/2/21/sspug-retrospective-creating-knockout-user-experiences-in-sh.html)

Comment: Hi Jordan, 

simply I want to get SharePoint list Items  and same time bind to GridView using JavaScript/JQuery. (SharePoint Client Object Model)

I need write in .ascx file only not in .ascx.cs file.

I am so happy if you provide any reference blogs/code.